# Promises with nested forEach loops generating resolve value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'd like to resolve this promise with 'content', after it is populated by a couple of forEach loops.

```
 'use strict';

 const {promisify} = require('util');

 const fs = require('fs');
 const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile);
 const readDirAsync = promisify(fs.readdir);
 const writeFileAsync = promisify(fs.writeFile);


function writeImportStatement(filepath) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let content = '';
    readDirAsync(`${filepath}/scss`)
      .then((files) => {
          files.forEach((file) => {
              fs.stat(`${filepath}/scss/${file}`, (err, stats) => {
                      if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                          readDirAsync(`${filepath}/scss/${file}`)
                          .then(scssfiles => {
                              scssfiles.forEach((scssfile) => {
                                  content += `@import "${filepath}/scss/${file}/${scssfile}"; \n`;
                              });
                          })
                      }
              });
          });
            console.log("loging import statement content: " + content);
            resolve(content);
      });
})
}
```

At the moment it is undefined.

Comment: You are resolving the promise before are values you are reading from files gets resolved.

Comment: The second `readDirAsync` needs to be promisfied.

Comment: @joseatchang Yes I figured as much. How to resolve the issue is not clear to me though.

Comment: You can wrap when you read all files into promises then use `Promise.all` to read all, and then resolve that result. But I think nesting promises in that way maybe is not a clean solution.

Answer (score -1):

I changed this over to async/await to make it a bit easier to read, it looks like your main problem is that your `files.forEach` needs to be wrapped in a `Promise.all` with each iteration returning a promise - if you want to stick with only promises instead of async/await, your final `console.log` and `resolve` would need to be in the `then` statement of that `Promise.all`.

```js
'use strict';

 const {promisify} = require('util');

 const fs = require('fs');
 const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile);
 const readDirAsync = promisify(fs.readdir);
 const writeFileAsync = promisify(fs.writeFile);


function writeImportStatement(filepath) {
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let content = '';
    const files = await readDirAsync(`${filepath}/scss`)
    const done = await Promise.all(files.forEach(async (file) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.stat(`${filepath}/scss/${file}`, async (err, stats) => {
          if(err) reject(err)
          if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            const scssfiles = await readDirAsync(`${filepath}/scss/${file}`)
            scssfiles.forEach((scssfile) => {
              content += `@import "${filepath}/scss/${file}/${scssfile}"; \n`;
            })
          }
          resolve()
        });
      });
    });
    console.log("loging import statement content: " + content);
    resolve(content);
})
}
```